# XAML/WPF: Tabbing to textboxes that are inside a tab

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF/XAML form that has controls on the page and also controls inside a tab control.

I was hoping that by setting the tabindex values appropriately, the user could just tab from the controls outside of the tab control to the controls inside the first tab item, but it seems that the items inside tab control are skipped when tabbing around the form.

Is there a way to have the tabbing go into the tabitem/tab control?

Comment: post your current XAML

Answer (score 1):

WPF provides a number of ways to affect the tab order in an application. Probably the most important is also strangely the least known. I'm talking about the `KeyboardNavigation` class and in particular, the [`KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation` Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabnavigation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). From the linked page on MSDN, this property *Gets or sets the logical tab navigation behavior for the children of the element that this property is set on*.

There are several possible values in the [`KeyboardNavigationMode` Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) used that affect the tabbing order in different ways. Take a look at the last linked page to see which one suits your situation best, but as an example, the `Local` value has the effect that *Tab Indexes are considered on local subtree only inside this container and ... [Navigation leaves the containing element when an edge is reached]*.

```
<Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
    ...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I've often faced and it's a tricky one. From my understanding, the reason that it doesn't work as you'd expect is because tab order (even specified via `TabIndex`) is contextual. TabIndex of higher level items will be prioritized over inner elements. So if you have two `TabItem`s inside of a `TabControl`, and each one has `UIElement`s inside of them, even if the `TabIndex` is specified, tabbing will first traverse the `TabItem`s before it moves down to the contents of those controls. I "think", IIRC" this has to do with how the page is composed, but don't quote me on that. MS has weird reasons for some of these subtle nuances.

Onto the solution. What I've done in the past (so long as you're NOT working on WinRT, which makes this problem even worse) you can use [UIElement.Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I store a list of `UIElement`s in the order I wish them to be when tabbed in the code. Then, by binding the `KeyDown` event to a common handler for all of these controls, I do something like this:

```
int currentIndex = TabbableControls.IndexOf(sender);
UIElement next = TabbableControls[(currentIndex + 1) % TabbableControls.Length];
next.Focus();
```

Hope this helps!